# Nodejs response is sending inaccurrate response

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to send a status(200) and the object of the user that was modified as a response to my unit test.

Currently I have the user found being logged with `console.log(users[id])` but on the response is an unexpected array of objects, index 0 being the expected modified user.

How can I send the user as an object?

```
  addForum:function(req,res,next) {
    //problem im sending an array of objects response to the test
    //need to only send an object so the array can check it
    var user
    console.log('This is Checker');
    if(req.body.add)console.log('true',req.body.add);
    else console.log(false,req.body.add);
    if(req.body.add){
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(users[i].id==req.params.id){
          AddtoUser(i)
        }
      }
    }
    function AddtoUser(id) {
      users[id].favorites.push(req.body.add)
      console.log('found',users[id]);
      res.json(users[id])

    }

    //  res.status(404).send()}
    next()


  },
```

Comment: The problem is probably where you construct the `add` field on the client to be submitted. How is your unit test generating that data?

Comment: The unit test calls this function with random data one that exist in the data set and one that doesnt. the test sends an id that my functons searches and a request on the body to add. All is good until the unit test checks the response send from my function it is returned as an array. it is expecting an object

Comment: `users[id]` is an array of objects, so this is doing exactly what you coded. You would need to do `users[id].favorites[0]` send the item you pushed into the array.

Comment: I logged the users[id] before sending the response and it is an object without a key

Comment: I see. What does `console.log(typeof users[id])` log?

Comment: Object, Array.isArray(users[id] = false